# Convert MySQL strings

Tags: mysql

Even what I propose is silly but I can not find an effective solution. In a MySQL table, I have a field that returns me a numeric string of variable length, that is, it can have 5 digits, 6, 7, etc.

The question, how can I insert to that value a specific character between characters?

For example, I get 473928 and I want to transform it into another field for an operation on / 4/7/3/9/2/8, that is, simply insert a "/" between the numbers.

I know it can be done with `substr ()`, but I run into the problem that since the length can be variable, I don't see a way to make it effective for any value that can be returned, that is:

135 -> / 1/3/5 3875 -> / 3/8/7/5 etc.

It may seem simple, but I can't find a way, do you know any of you?

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(source_value, '\\d', '/$0') ...`

Comment: try ```implode("/",str_split("473928"))```

Comment: Hi Akina2, the returns value for a string "509921" is "/$0/$0/$0/$0/$0/$0", when desired "/5/0/9/9/2/1", what's is wrong?

Comment: SaachiTech, "implode" is not a MySQL function, I want to return the value in SELECT statement. Thanks